# I'm having error as regards deleting document from firebase. The error is coming from the fileId

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js13, zustand

```
  async function deleteFile() {
    if (!user || !fileId) return;

    // the pat to the file we want to delete. this indicates the location of the file we want to delete
    const fileRef = sRef(storage, `users/${user.id}/files/${fileId}`);
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.id, "files", fileId);
    // const docRef = db.doc("users/user.id/files/fileId");

    try {
      deleteObject(fileRef).then(async () => {
        deleteDoc(docRef).then(() => {
          console.log("Delete!");
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    setIsDeleteModalOpen(false);
  }
```

I have the fileId from an zustand appstore which I am passing through the deleteDoc from firestore but it throws an error.

This is actually a dropboxclone from sonny sangha on youtube ,I have debbugged and searched articles but to no avail.  [[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dMKH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf1je.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpcao.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Ok .Noted Thanks for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are one two many `state.isDeleteModalOpen` lines in your `useAppStore` call which means that `fileId` is not set to the right value. Remove this extra `state.isDeleteModalOpen` line.

---

Looking at your linting error we can discern that one of the path arguments is not a string.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(firestore: Firestore, path: string, ...pathSegments: string[]): DocumentReference<DocumentData, DocumentData>', gave the following error:
  Argument of type: '(open: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

```js
const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.id, "files", fileId);
// either user.id or fileId is not a string
```

Taking a closer look at your `useAppStore` destructuring call:

```js
const [isDeleteModalOpen, setIsDeleleModalOpen, fileId, setFileId] =
  useAppStore((state) => [
    state.isDeleteModalOpen,
    state.setIsDeleleModalOpen,
    state.setIsDeleleModalOpen,
    state.fileId,
    state.setFileId
  ]);

// fileId is a '(open: boolean) => void' (and was set to state.setIsDeleleModalOpen)
```

As can be seen above, you have 5 array elements being destructured as an array of 4 elements. Removing the extra line fixes this problem.

```js
const [isDeleteModalOpen, setIsDeleleModalOpen, fileId, setFileId] =
  useAppStore((state) => [
    state.isDeleteModalOpen,
    state.setIsDeleleModalOpen,
    state.fileId,
    state.setFileId
  ]);

// fileId is a 'string' (and was set to state.fileId)
```